# React-typeScript: Cypress Test

Tags: cypress, react-typescript

I am really new in [Cypress Test](https://www.cypress.io/). I am using React-typescript for my app. I want to test react default App component. I really don't how to test it. when I write test like this:

```
describe('dd', () => {
  it('', () => {
    cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/') 
   
  })
})
```

It throws me error. Like this:

[image]

After run the app then it test does not show me error. Is it the right way to test?

**Second when i test the link like this:**

```
describe('dd', () => {
  it('', () => {
    cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/')
    cy.get(`App-link`).should('be.visiable').and("have.text", "Learn React")
  })
})
```

I got an error:

[image]

**I am using Eslint for my app and this is the setup:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

is there any boiler plate for React-typescript and Cypress?

Comment: 1. The site has to be served by *something* for Cypress to browse to it. 2. Cypress shouldn't know or care that React is involved; don't select by React components, select by the resulting HTML. [Here](https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit-ts) is a starter kit I set up where Cypress tests a React UI (all in TS).

Comment: It looks like css locator of app link is wrong, please share the html so we can locate element

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry mate. you starter kit does not work. I am getting same error

Comment: I don't know what you've done, but `npm run e2e` has successfully run half a dozen times today alone: https://travis-ci.com/github/textbook/starter-kit-ts/builds. If there's a specific problem running any of the scripts in that template, please raise an issue on the repo with a [mre].

Comment: this is my github repo: https://github.com/alakdam07/cypress-test

Comment: @jonrsharpe do i have to run the app `npm start` then test? when I run the app then `npm run e2e` it works.

Comment: Yes, you have to start the app, as I said in my first comment. In the starter kit I shared I use [`concurrently`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) to serve the app and run Cypress at the same time.

Comment: Oh ok sir. Sorry I am really new in Cypress, I did not know that. And english is not my first language :D. Thank you for help me out.